# Gitlab clone branch in CI

Tags: git, gitlab, continuous-integration

I am trying to test specified branch in gitlab CI first one is working properly but in second one I am getting "unable to access Illegal port number" error.

**--- First ---**

```
Bootstrap KDE:
  stage: .pre
  script:
    - git clone https://gitlab-ci-token:${CI_JOB_TOKEN}@gitlab.abc.zone/qa/cloud.git qa-cloud
```

**--- Second ---**

```
Bootstrap KDE:
  stage: .pre
  script:
    - git clone https://gitlab-ci-token:${CI_JOB_TOKEN}@gitlab.abc.zone:qa/cloud.git -b Coverage-Check-for-LoadTesting   qa-cloud
```

**---Error---**

```
fatal: unable to access Illegal port number
```

Answer (score 0):

OMG
it is a typo causing this issue. error message is not informative on the contrary, it is misleading

```
- .abc.zone:qa/c.
+ .abc.zone/qa/c
```